# ASP.NET MVC Caching vary by controller action parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, outputcache

Is there any way I can vary caching by a controller action parameter using the [outputcache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.108).aspx) attribute? We have [varybyparam](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybyparam(v=vs.108).aspx) which will not work if my parameters are embedded within the URL in a REST manner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caching works this way by default.  Different URLs give different cache locations.  Perhaps there is something missing from your question, but, as stated, it already works this way.

Answer (score 10):

Its also important to realize in a Action method that 'VaryByParam' does not mean 'Vary by the parameters being passed into that action method'. it means 'vary by the parameters being passed into that action method that originate as HTTP parameters'.

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "ContentPage", VaryByParam = "mode")]
public ActionResult Index(string key, string mode)
{

}
```

Lets say the route for this action method is :

```
  routes.MapRoute(
   "video-route-short",
   "video/{key}",
   new { controller = "Video", action = "Index", key = (string)null }
  );
```

As Craig says above, the key parameter is part of the URL and therefore caching doesn't apply to it - so it is essentially always cached.

The mode parameter which would be sent via a '`?mode=1`' type would apply to the caching.

Comment: As of MVC3 this is no longer the case [see](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518671/does-varybyparam-also-read-routedata-values)