# OutputCache and injected ActionParameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, outputcache, actionfilterattribute

We use a ActionFilterAttribute to inject some parameters into actions and it works great.

But when we add OutputCache it varies exclusively on "MyID" when Html.RenderAction() is used and not when surfing directly to the action.

Any ideas how to get OutputCache to always recognize "MyID"?

**Controller**

```
[SiteIDs, OutputCache]
public ActionResult SiteContent(string myID)
{
    return Content(myID);
}
```

**ActionFilter**

```
public class SiteIDs : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("MyID"))
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters["MyID"] = GetMyIDByHostname();
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the OutputCacheAttribute, action filters will not execute when a page is retrieved from the cache. You should probably use [mvcdonutcaching](https://github.com/moonpyk/mvcdonutcaching) in order to have the action filters executed even when retrieving from the cache. I'd recommend reading [this](http://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/donut-output-caching-in-asp.net-mvc-3).

Comment: I have tried MvcDonutCaching now and my ActionFilter runs every time but it does not work (neither via Html.RenderAction() or directly).
I also looked at the source for both and it seems like [OutputCache] uses ActionParameters and [DonutOutputCache] RouteData when generating a key.

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518671/does-varybyparam-also-read-routedata-values#8710876), you just need to use `VaryByParam = "*"` and it will automatically vary by the parameters you pass the action method.

```
[SiteIDs, OutputCache(VaryByParam = "*")]
public ActionResult SiteContent(string myID)
{
    return Content(myID);
}
```

However, that may not work by using an `IActionFilter` (haven't tried it). You might try using an [`IValueProvider`](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/smart-working-with-custom-value-providers-in-Asp-Net-mvc/) instead (which is a cleaner way to do what you are doing with the action filter, anyway).

## Option 2

You could use [VaryByCustom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybycustom.aspx) and [GetVaryByCustomString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.getvarybycustomstring.aspx) to vary the cache by hostname.

```
[SiteIDs, OutputCache(VaryByParam = "none", VaryByCustom = "hostname")]
public ActionResult SiteContent(string myID)
{
    return Content(myID);
}
```

And in your `Global.asax` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
    }

    public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
    {
        if (custom == "hostname")
        {
            return "HostName=" + context.Request.Url.Host;
        }

        return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, custom);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind your action filter will only be hit if the `OutputCache` has not been set. So you need to vary the cache on the same value (or values) that you vary your `ID` from. The simplest solution is to use something that is already in `HttpContext`, such as host name.

Comment: Option 1: Yes, VaryByParam = "*" is default and it works with a IActionFilter when Html.RenderAction("MyAction", "MyController", new { notIncludingMyIDInRouteValueDictinary = "foo" }) is used but not when accessing the Action directly.

I tried with a IValueProvider today, no difference.

Option 2: Have not tried this yet.